# Which type of binding is used in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I know JavaScript uses lexical scoping and it is the reason closures can be created in JavaScript.

But, what about static or dynamic binding in regards of JavaScript. 
I couldn't find a proper and clear answer of this question.

I would be glad if anyone put some light on this topic .

Comment: JavaScript is not a compiled language so there is no static binding. There are certain errors that thrown before a JavaScript program is executed, but this are usually all syntax related.

Comment: Could you please explain it with an example?

Comment: http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs3304/Spring04/notes/Chapter-4/tsld009.htm explains it very succinctly. As Felix says, this really doesn't apply to JavaScript, because there's no compile-time step, the code is just interpreted direct from the source (assuming it can be parsed - if it can't, you get a syntax error). Which is probably why you couldn't find much material about the topic.

Comment: Example: `var foo = {}; foo.bar()` will throw an error at **run time** (dynamic), not at *compile time* (static) because there is no compile time.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in the comments, since JavaScript isn't compiled, there can't be static binding. Everything is dynamic.

When you run JavaScript, it is just read from the top down. This means, that as long as there aren't errors, it'll keep going. Even if you have a syntax error, it'll still run and execute up to that point.

```js
console.log('A');
console.log('B');
console.log(C); // undefined variable throws error
```

This is different from languages like Java and C#, which have to have all of their syntax errors fixed before they can finish compiling and running.

Comment: *"Even if you have a syntax error, it'll still run and execute up to that point."* Nope, that's not correct. The script cannot be executed if there is a *syntax* error. The JavaScript engine will still parse the whole script before actually executes it.

Comment: The example you've given isn't a syntax error, it's a runtime error due to an undefined variable. Your explanation is a bit misleading. As Felix mentions, a syntax error would cause the script not to run at all. After all, if you think about it, a syntax error means the interpreter cannot understand the code that has been written - therefore, how can it possibly execute any of it? The code does not make sense to the interpreter in that situation. In your example, by contrast, the code makes sense to the interpreter,but there happens to be a logical error in that a variable is not given a value